# How to get struts2 HttpServletReponse using xmlhttp request

Tags: jsp, struts2, xmlhttprequest, activexobject

My struts.xml part

```
<action name="viewall" class="com.abc.csm.actions.GetAllConfiguration">
         <result name="success">/success.jsp</result>
    </action>
```

on Page load of Welcome.jsp i call a function `getXml()` which should receive xml as a response but instead i get `success.jsp` content

```
function getXml()
{
 var url_action="/csm/viewall.action";
 var client; 
 var dataString;

 if (window.XMLHttpRequest){ 
     client=new XMLHttpRequest();
 } else {                    
     client=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
 }

 client.onreadystatechange=function(){

     if(client.readyState==4&&client.status==200)
     {
         alert(client.responseText); /* here i want to get the actual response i.e., my xml. I am also using fiddler to monitor. */

     }
 };

 dataString="projectid=1-105101";
 client.open("POST",url_action,true);
 client.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

 client.send(dataString);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In struts.xml you have:

```
<result name="success">/success.jsp</result>
```

This is the same as:

```
<result type="dispatcher" name="success">/success.jsp</result>
```

The dispatcher result type is the default and it means, render the jsp.  This is what is happening, you are getting the result of the jsp and not xml.

Here is a list of the built in result types: http://struts.apache.org/2.0.6/docs/result-types.html  The xslt result type may interest you.  If you don't mind working in JSON, adding the struts2-json-plugin to your class path gives you the json result type which is very easy to use too.

**Edit**: You may also use the stream result.

Comment: I tried `<result type="xslt" name="success">/success.jsp</result>` but it does not work. and there is no xml type

Comment: I don't have experience with the xslt type.  For ajax I use JSON it is rather easy to work with. The benefit of xml shows up when you need a formalized inter-business format.  I've used the stream result type (for pdfs) and would probably try that before xslt.

Comment: You can also use the dispatcher result type and map it to a JSP that renders XML rather than HTML.

Comment: Yes that would work too! Lots of options. If the OP would like to go that route there's an example on this page: http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/xml/WebAppDev2/